# After 'removing' Ubuntu from MacBook it cannot boot to OSX but loads Grub 2

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

So, I installed a dual-boot solution for Mac to use Ubuntu for C programming. I used rEFInd to dual boot between OSX and Ubuntu. Now I'm done with my C programming course, I wanted to delete this partition and restore to SingleBoot OSX. I tried removing the Ubuntu partition from Disk Utilities and everything seemed fine, however the partition was still there (disk utility only emptied it to my knowledge) therefore I wanted to check out the Recovery Boot by using Command+R to get into Disk Recovery Utilities, but since then I am unable to boot into OSX Yosemite.

Trying to remove the Ubuntu partition in Disk Utilities probably triggered this.

These are my options (as far as I know):

**When normal boot**: It shows me 'Grub 2' with a black/white prompt, I am unfamiliar with this and I found some things on the internet that I tried to boot from Grub into OSX but I can't seem to make it work.
- When asking for my partitions(`ROOT (hd1+TAB`, it gives me these:

```
Partition hd1,gpt1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'EFI', UUID 67E3-17ED -
  Partition start at 20KiB - Total size 204800KiB
Partition hd1,gpt2: No known filesystem detected - 
  Partition start at 204820KiB - Total size 234298724KiB
Partition hd1,gpt3: Filesystem type hfsplus - Label 'Recovery HD' - 
  Last modification time 2016-11-24 09:24:50 Thursday, UUID 9b4a0f2de0c6bcdb - 
  Partition start at 234503544KiB- Total size 634768KiB
Partition hd1,gpt4: Filesystem type hfsplus - Label 'Naamloos' - 
  Last modification time 2016-11-24 09:24:50 Thursday, UUID 75f3078817440770 -
  Partition start at 235138312KiB - Total size 9847656.5KiB
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd0'.
```

**When recovery boot (CMD+R)**

I get into OS X Recovery with Internet acces, where I can try to connect to a WiFi network, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I connect to my own WiFi, it just keeps spinning in loading screen as if it fails to connect (it doesn't crash cause I can still abort the operation).

**When choosing startup disk boot (OPTION/ALT)**

This gives me a list of bootable disks, but only 'Recovery HD' is in the list.
It also gives me the option to connect to WiFi.
When choosing Recovery Disk, all seems pretty normal:
- Looks like OSX is loading
- Loads up OSX startup screen, asking for password (even has my correct user picture)
- When given correct password: slowly loads white bar till about half and then suddenly shows a black screen with a white 'Prohibited' sign ( ⃠)

If anyone knows any solutions or credible tutorials/articles/videos on how to solve my problem (if only it brings me into some sort of recovery mode that I can use), please let me know!

If you need any more information (or pictures), let me know!

Thanks alot in advance, I am in mild panic at the moment.

EDIT: I tried Recovery with Internet again on a different WiFi and it took a minute, then it went to blackscreen en now it says; "apple.com/support  -2003F"

Comment: For future advice, I'd just use a virtual machine for Ubuntu rather than dual booting.

Comment: This is the exact reason for why I wanted to remove Ubuntu from my mac as a Dual-Boot option, because I already had Ubuntu working ultimately in a VM-environment. But the assignments I had to make kind of required me to have Ubuntu outside of VM since I needed the audio device to work properly for programming in C.

Comment: gotcha. I too learned the hard way. I realized it was a lot easier to blow away a VM if needed and start over lol. Do you have any data on your Mac that you consider valuable?

Comment: Yes! I really want my photos, videos and music back and my university assignments I would like to have back. If you are knowledgeable about options, consider giving my other post at community 'apple' a read:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/how-do-i-recover-fix-my-mac-os-partition

Comment: I'll surely give it a look later on. Which OS were you running?

Comment: I was running OS X El Capitan

Comment: Hi Bart, have you found a solution to this?
I'm stuck in the same situation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Find a friend with a bootable USB drive with MacOS (preferably Yosemite) installed on it (since I assume you don't have one, and it's now too late for you to make one), and boot from that. Then you can use Disk Utility to check out your main drive, and if necessary reinstall MacOS.

Comment: Thanks! I am the only one atm at my house with an Apple computer, so I won't be able to do that at this moment since I don't think you can create readable bootable USBs from a Windows computer (which I am on right now). Will ask someone on my university though, thanks alot.